# My buttons are floating away from my second menu

Tags: html, css

HTML code

```
<div class="heading"></div>
<hr/>
<div class="menu">
    <nav>
        <a href="#1">Home</a>
        <a href="#3">History</a>
        <a href="#4">Gallery</a>
        <a href="#5">Contacts</a>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="box1">
        <div class="menu1">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#6">Documents</a></li>
                <li><a href="#7">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#8">Izvunklasni</a></li>
                <li><a href="#9">Postijeniq</a></li>
                <li><a href="#10">Priem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#11">News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#12">Parents</a></li>
                <li><a href="#13">Students</a></li>
                <li><a href="#14">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#15">Film</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code :

```
h1 {
    text-align:center;
}
.heading {
    height:136px;
    width:950px;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:table;
    background:url("banner5.gif") no-repeat;
    background-color:white;
}
.box {
    height:900px;
    width:950px;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:table;
    background-color:#8F8F8F;
}
hr {
    width:600px;
}
body {
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
.menu {
    margin:0 auto;
    display:table;
}
.menu1 {
}
a {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:5px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
.box1 {
    margin:15px 15px;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color:#999999;
    height:400px;
    width:100px;
}
a:link {
    background-color:grey;
}
a:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
a:active {
    background-color:violet;
}
```

Problem is that my second menu is floating away . It's the one in the "menu1" class . Also does some one know do I need somethink in CSS about "menu1" class , or I should leave it alone . Sorry for the stupid question , but I didn't practice CSS for a while , because I was learning JavaScript and jQuery . Apritiate you help

Comment: What do you mean "float away" can you set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by jsfiddle , but I mean that float in different directions around my "box" class . I wan't them to be on top of each other in "box1" class .

Comment: When I add this code you wrote in fiddle it displays different . The second menu is ok , but the first menu on top is without borter-radius , padding , etc....

Comment: Here is the js fiddle (online example); http://fiddle.jshell.net/Q4rRN/6/show/ See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Although its not clear what excatly you are looking. but just saw the design I am guessing you are having problem the `list item` are out from the flow and not inside the  `div` ofcourse you you will need `.menu1` class
to clear the `left` property because you use `float:left` in `a` tag.

So what I did here clear the `float` using `clear:left`

```
.menu1 {clear:left;}
.menu1 ul{ list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
```

Check the ***[Demo](http://jsbin.com/quduxumo/9/)***.

Comment: what do you mean to say?

Answer (score 0):

```
ul li{
    list-style: none;
}
.box {
height:900px;
width:950px;
border:1px solid black;
border-radius:5px;
margin:0 auto;
background-color:#8F8F8F;
}
.box1{
margin:15px 15px;
border:1px solid black;
border-radius:5px;
background-color:#999999;
height:400px;
display: table;
}
.menu1{
padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Q4rRN/6/
http://fiddle.jshell.net/Q4rRN/6/show/

Also fixed some UX design issues by adding space to the list items.

```
.menu1 ul {
list-style:none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

.menu1 ul li {
margin-bottom:5px;
display:block;
}

.menu1 a,
nav a {
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
border:1px solid #000;
border-radius:5px;
display:block;
float:left;
padding:5px 10px;
}

.menu1 a {
display:block;
float:none;
}

.box1 {
background-color:#999;
border:1px solid #000;
border-radius:5px;
float:left;
margin:15px;
padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: best answer . Thanks alot man . BTW how did you make the buttons have the same size ?

Comment: display: block on the a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply resetting the list elements for the menu

Add this to your css

```
.menu1 ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0; 
    list-style-type:none;    
}
```

Obviously there's a lot more styling you can do but this should address the "float" issue

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jby8n/